# Problem with Octave. Can't recognize a matrix

Tags: octave

I try to build a script on Octave and I receive this message:

```
error: script2: =: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 1x10)
error: called from
    script2 at line 5 column 1
```

My script is:

```
l = 20:29;
m = 30;

for i = 0:9
  a(i + 1) = l / m;
end
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: What's `a`? Did you mean `l(i + 1) / m`? Why not count from 1 to 10?

Comment: A is a matrix which should contain all the values from l/m. It counts from 0 to 9 because of the values 20 to 29

Comment: If you initialize `a` somewhere, you should show that. Right now the error is telling you that you're trying to stuff 10 elements into 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Octave allows you to assign to a non-existent name by making a scalar. You can then append to it by assigning to an index that is one past the length.

When you assign to `a(1)`, `a` is created as a scalar (or 1x1 array). `l / m` is 1x10. That is what your error message is telling you.

There are a couple of workarounds. If you want to just accumulate the rows of a matrix, add a second dimension:

```
a(i + 1, :) = l / m;
```

If you want columns:

```
a(:, i + 1) = l / m;
```

The problem with this approach is that it reallocates the matrix at every iteration. The recommended approcach is to pre-allocate the matrix `a` and fill it in:

```
l = 20:29;
m = 30;
a = zeros(10);

for i = 1:10
  a(i + 1, :) = l / m;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Octave is capable of doing matrix operations, you don't need the `for` loop in the first place.
I would rather write:

```
l = 20:29;
m = 30;
a = l / m;
```

This is much more efficient.